# How to parse any json file in Dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Is it possible to have one function to read any json file with any structure? The application will read different json data that are not known in advance, I need to have a function that can process any json file.

Comment: if you mean parsing `String` to `dynamic` hierarchical data then yes: [json](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/json-constant.html)`.decode()` - for example `final decoded = json.decode('["foo", { "bar": 499 }]');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [dart_convert](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) library you can parse a json string to a map using `Map<String, dynamic> yourMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);`

Answer (score 0):

First you should build a Json Model and then convert it to object

**Json :**

```
[{"code": 401,"message": "No data found"}]
```

**json to model :**

```
class ResponseModel {
 int code;
 String message;
 
  ResponseModel({this.code, this.message});

  ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   code = json['code'];
   message = json['message'];
  }

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  data['code'] = this.code;
  data['message'] = this.message;
  return data;
 }
}
```

**convert json to Object LIst**

```
      List<ResponseModel> lists =                        List<ResponseModel>.from(json.decode(response.body).map((x) => ResponseModel.fromJson(x)));
```

Comment: I don't know which json model I'm getting.